# Was Jennifer Aniston really naked in front of the Friends audience?

Tags: production, friends

A live audience attended the studio to watch the making of Friends. (https://www.quora.com/Are-sitcoms-like-Friends-and-HIMYM-really-recorded-in-front-of-an-audience-Are-the-laughs-original, 
http://www.comedycentral.co.uk/friends/articles/25-interesting-facts-about-the-live-filming-of-friends)

There is a scene when Rachel Green is naked in the apartment:

[image]

Was she really naked in front of the studio audience? What if there were children in the audience?

Comment: What makes you think there WAS an audience? Friends used a laugh track

Comment: @Paulie_D Cause of this link https://www.quora.com/Are-sitcoms-like-Friends-and-HIMYM-really-recorded-in-front-of-an-audience-Are-the-laughs-original  and this link http://www.comedycentral.co.uk/friends/articles/25-interesting-facts-about-the-live-filming-of-friends and many other sources said so.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Please leave that as an answer to the question, not a comment. Comments don't have the quality assurance mechanisms that answers do. (And it would indeed be a good answer.)

Comment: "What if there were children in the audience?" [WON'T SOMEBODY PLEASE THINK OF THE CHILDREN?!?](https://rarlomagazine.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/wont-somebody-please-think-of-the-children.gif)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, most likely not. Usually for shows that are recorded in front of an audience, nude scenes are pre-recorded on a closed set. Even if they were recorded live, the actor would most definitely have pasties on. Therefor, they aren't nude in front of a live audience even if it was recorded in front of a live audience.